# Changing icon for only askopenfilename in tkinter, while hiding the main Tk() window in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to change the window icon **only for askopenfilename window** in tkinter, **while hiding the main Tk() window**, but when I use `Tk().iconbitmap("myIcon.ico")` before `Tk().withdraw()`, while icon is changed, the root window is still not gone.

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

window_icon = 'icon.ico'[enter image description here][1]


Tk().iconbitmap(window_icon)
Tk().withdraw()  # keep the root window from appearing

filename = str(askopenfilename(title='Select an image file', initialdir='')
```

If i remove this line: `Tk().iconbitmap("myIcon.ico")` then it works fine with window spawning but then there is no icon on the window.

I want to remove this root window, as shown in image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJm0R.png

Also, please suggest if I can use a PIL code to convert saved jpg file into temp ico file data which can be used instead of `myIcon.ico`? Because this method of icon changing takes .ico file as input and I am convenient with jpg.

Thankyou

PS: This is my first question on stackoverflow!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have created two instances of `Tk()`:

```py
Tk().iconbitmap(window_icon) # first instance
Tk().withdraw()  # 2nd instance
```

So you just hide the second instance.

Create single instance of `Tk()` instead:

```py
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()  # keep the root window from appearing
root.iconbitmap(window_icon)
```

---

You can use JPEG image as the icon using `Pillow` (`PIL` clone) module:

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from PIL import ImageTk

root = Tk()
window_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="icon.jpg")
root.iconphoto(True, window_icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps,

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.iconbitmap("YOUR_IMAGE.ico")
file = askopenfilename(title="YOUR_WINDOW_TITLE", filetypes=[("text files", "*.txt")])
```

*Hope this will work for you!*